# Using Tuleap Agile Dashboard

Tags: linux, project-management

When planning a release using the Agile Dashboard it appears that the slide function - remove the backlog to a release does not work on my environment.

Note that I play the role of administrator on the project, and at the level of releases I can not find the words 'This element is empty, please drag anything here' and I can't find any specific information in the documentation.

Tuleap Agile Dashboard was installed from the package 'RPMForge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm' in a Unix environment.

Can anyone put me on the right track? Can anyone provide me with a solution for it?

Comment: Super User is an English-only site, and all the questions and answers must be in English.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart http server `service httpd restart`. If it Does not work could you tell us which version of Tuleap you are using and if you have any error in your javascript console on this page?

-- Martin

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS6 I had exactly the same issue.

I resolved it by updating the packages

```
yum update
```

and then restarting httpd and tuleap

```
service httpd restart && service tuleap restart
```

It seems like it was just not up to date!

Hope it helps